# How do you plot a neural network in R without the excluded weights?

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-networks

I have a neural network with a lot of weights that I have fitted with neuralnet. I exclude a lot of weights that I deem unnecessary, but they are still included in the plot, and this takes a long time to plot. Is there any way to exclude them from being drawn in the plot?

Maybe there's a nice package for this?